# Extreme point and affine map

Tags: functional-analysis

The problem in Conway's Functional analysis book : 
[image]

I know that
$x$ is called an extreme point of $A$ if $x_1, x_2\in A$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)$ imply $x_1=x_2$.

And if $T$ is an affine map, then $T(\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2))=\frac{1}{2}T(x_1)+\frac{1}{2}T(x_2)$.

But I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: If $y = \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$ and $y_1 = y_2$, then $y_1 = y_2 = y$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I already know that.. Could you give me more hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be an extreme point of $T^{-1}(y)$ and $x = \frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2 \in K$. Then
$$y = T(x) = \frac{1}{2}(T(x_1) + T(x_2)).$$
As $y$ is an extreme point of $T(K)$, this implies that $y = T(x_1) = T(x_2)$. But then $x_1,x_2$ are elements of $T^{-1}(y)$ and since $x$ is an extreme point of $T^{-1}(y)$ we have $x = x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Thank you for very nice answer.